# Use DogeScript in my website?

Tags: javascript

I'm kind of embarrassed to ask this, but I have noticed "DogeScript" which supposedly compiles into JavaScript. Is this real or is the whole thing just  prank. And there is a syntax, which is funny as hell, which is why I want to use it. 
If it is real, how can I use it in my website?

Comment: [Yes it's real.](https://dogescript.com/) Just follow the instructions on their website to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The [dogescript website](https://dogescript.com/) says it can be installed using npm -- so probably very much like coffeescript, it would require you using nodejs/meteor or that you precompiled the script to javascript if you are using a different webserver.